# Just Installed Ubuntu how do i boot from my C: drive?

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, usb

So I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 onto my C: drive from a usb flash drive, how do I boot from it?

- CPU: Intel i5-4440
- Mobo: Acer MS-7869
- RAM: 2x4 Kingston (or something xd) HYper fury x ram
- Graphics: Intel Graphics 4400?
- 2tb hdd. I've got 2 virtual drives `C:` and `D:`, 1tb each.

I’m using Ubuntu, now I've installed it but how would I boot from it as if I turned my pc and on would it go back to my USB flash drive installer? Or straight to Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you saying you have Ubuntu installed on both your `C:` drive and your `D:` drive?

Comment: I think its my C: drive but it has installed one drive not both im sure of that

Comment: Is there an operating system on the `D:` drive?

Comment: The only OS i have is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Which i think is on my C: drive

Comment: So for the future I'd like to say to you that there is no `C:` or  `D:` drive in Ubuntu. There are only partitions or how you named them "virtual drives".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not your system boots off of the USB drive or the internal hard drive you just installed Ubuntu onto depends on 2 factors:

1. Whether or not the USB drive is still plugged in
2. If your BIOS/UEFI boot order has USB drive prioritized above or below the internal hard drive.

The easiest solution would be to just remove the USB drive, and boot up your computer. That will boot up into Ubuntu 14.04, regardless of what drive it is installed on, because it's the only OS available.

If you want to change your boot order, there is a function key that you will need to hold down, and that function key is motherboard-specific. Look on the bottom of the screen as you turn on the computer, and it has the computer manufacturer on the screen. On the bottom there will be something like `Settings: F7`, or similar. Press that button, and you will be taken to your BIOS/UEFI settings.

Comment: so thats all i had to? just take it out and turn my pc on then it will boot onto Ubuntu?

Comment: @Isaac if this solved your problem, please mark it as Answered by clicking the checkmark under the downvote button! :D

Comment: @Isaac Correct!

Comment: yay :3 ill mark it correct now

Comment: how do i do that xd

Comment: @Isaac Under the `0` to the left of my answer, there is an upside-down triangle, and then a wireframe checkmark. Click the checkmark.

Comment: btw this is unrelated to this xd but how do i scroll up faster in FireFox?

Comment: @Isaac I believe that in the Mouse section of `System Settings`, there is a scroll speed option.

Comment: thanks and one more thing xd how do i restart/sleep?

Comment: @Isaac So, the computer will automatically go to sleep, but to manually trigger it, you click the top-right corner, and choose `Suspend`, and to restart, you choose `Shutdown...`, and then choose `Restart` (the ... indicates it will open a dialogue). Welcome to Ubuntu!

Comment: @Isaac lol no problem!

Comment: I cant see my mouse o-o i restarted and i cant see my mouse now! it works but i cant see the cursor

Comment: @Isaac try rebooting again

Comment: @Isaac np mate :)

Answer (score 2):

**So you've just installed Ubuntu, what now ?**

When the installation USB reports to you that the installation process is over and you may reboot the computer, simplest course of action is to shutdown the computer , remove the USB, boot the computer. As explained in zwork's awesome answer ,  chances are that your computer has higher priority for booting USB devices than hard drives, and if it's so , it will check for USB disks plugged in and boot from them if they are present. By default the HDD should have boot priority, but you or someone else may have changed that setting in the bios.

**So installation media is out, computer is off, and I now boot it up. What may happen?**

There exists something known as [bootloader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting#Boot_sequence), the basic program that comes up and allows you to choose from the Operating Systems installed on your disk(s). By default, Ubuntu's bootloader (named GRUB) sets Ubuntu as default option. Again, this is something that you yourself or the person who was installing the OS would have to alter, so you can be sure in 99.99% of the time that it will go to Ubuntu.

If it does not boot at all, or there is some error, there's something seriously wrong, and there is need for troubleshooting.

**OK, well what about C and D and other drives ?**

Here's the difference between Ubuntu ( and Linux in general ) and Windows. Under Ubuntu disks are listed as devices, `/dev/sda` being the main disk. Disks in turn have [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning), chunks where OSs reside. For example, my HDD has `/dev/sda2` as Windows 7 partition and `/dev/sda5` Ubuntu partition. You will have something similar if you chose "Install alongside Windows" option during installation. Linux also uses something known as [swap partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap) - a way to use disk space as extra memory. On my SSD , I only have Ubuntu, so there is `/dev/sda1` , but to save disk space I didn't create swap.

**Let's come back to booting part. How do I know that I am booting from the same drive as windows ?**

Simplest way is through command line IMHO, hence showing you that. Open Terminal ( aka command-line, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> together ) and type `sudo blkid`. If you see multiple lines starting with `/dev/sdaX` (where X is a number ), and one of the lines says TYPE="ntfs", that means that's your Windows partition. Congrats ! You've installed Ubuntu side-by-side with Windows . If you don't see it, then you either intentionally or unintentionally clicked "errase the disk and install Ubuntu" option. Time to either use recovery DVD that came with the computer , save up for new Windows installation DVD, or just stick with Ubuntu and enjoy the ride.

Comment: wait Ive got '/dev/sda1' '/dev/sda2' '/dev/sda3' even though ive got one physical drive that is split into 2 1tb each, even though Ubuntu is my one and only OS I got rid of windows  have I installed UBuntu 14.04 wrong?

Comment: @Isaac run `sudo blkid` in terminal. What does it say ? One of the partitions should be TYPE="swap", TYPE="ext4" is Ubuntu. What is the other 3rd partition type ?

Comment: Its on the top and it says  TYPE=@

Comment: TYPE='vfat' then the next 2 are on the bottom

Comment: @Isaac that's  really weird . . . You sure you don't have a USB plugged in there ? and it's not named `/dev/sdb1` ?  How about output of `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT` ? Do you recoginze that partition's size or label ?

Comment: @Isaac once you get over 20 rep points on the site, you can join me and other users in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) , it will be easier to discuss long topics

Comment: xd looks messy wait ill post it on imgur and give you the link

Comment: http://imgur.com/BoodMxw

Comment: THe only things i have plugged in are: My headphones, Realtek Speakers, Mouse, Keyboard and my printer although my printer dosent even work with ubuntu it works with windows 7 so idk why that would cause any problems

Comment: I dont have a usb plugged it its just on my desk :P, infront of me  xd

Comment: @Isaac you probably need drivers for the printer. Search in the software center. Really better to do it in command line though. As for that vfat partition, I don't know. Someone in chat suggested that may be system partition (whatever that means ). Does your PC use  UEFI  ?

Comment: I think it uses BIOS but im not sure ill check now

Comment: Yeah it uses BIOS

Comment: Well, I dont know . . . But I'll ask around some more

Comment: Ok :3 thanks  this has to be a long comment to post xd

Answer (score 0):

If you have chosen "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", if you pull the USB out out should be able to boot from it with no problem. If you have only one hdd/ssd there is no more C: or D: partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that no other OS is present then GRUB should automatically load the available OS which is Ubuntu 14.04 in your case that is it would load Ubuntu when you turn your system 'on'. Moreover here you won't find the nomenclature used in windoes to mark drives i.e C: or D: etc, you will have your boot disk which may look something like /dev/sda 1/ and your other drives would take up the similar system of naming.